# Error connecting to Flet server, SocketException: Connection failed

Tags: python, flet

## [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnuxK.png)

I want to build serious_python apk, but this problem makes me unable to run 'flutter build apk --release'

I want there to be no error connecting to the server, and the flutter application will appear in the emulator

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.